# Error in Class CRM_Extension_Mapper 'Class CRM_Extension_Info not found' when installing 5.24 in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, installation

I have a problem enabling CiviCRM 5.24.2 after installation in Drupal 7.69 under PHP 7.2.27 under Centos7 Apache/2.4.6

CiviCRM installs correctly using both UI and CV method - ie builds database & civicrm.settings, but fails to enable (same error in both install methods).

`drush en -y civicrm` produces the following error (and breaks Drupal site):

```
WD php: Error: Class 'CRM_Extension_Info' not found in CRM_Extension_Mapper->keyToInfo()
Error: Class &#039;CRM_Extension_Info&#039; not found in CRM_Extension_Mapper->keyToInfo() (line 170 of /srv/web/climatebonds.net/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Extension/Mapper.php).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

`drush dis -y civicrm` returns site to working order.

No problems with installation under local environment: Apache/2.4.35 (Unix) PHP/7.2.19

Answer (score 1):

This issue fixed .. simply due to missing file in deployment.

Comment: Good to hear your problem is fixed.  Could you expand a bit on how the problem arose and what you did to fix it?